# Dynamically set text of Radtooltipmanager

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my .aspx code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="link" runat="server"> <telerik:RadToolTipManager
ID="toottip" runat="server" AutoTooltipify="true" Width="200px"
RelativeTo="Element"  HideEvent="LeaveTargetAndToolTip"
WebServiceSettings-UseHttpGet="false" Animation="Fade"  
EnableTheming="true" Title="Documents" ShowEvent="OnMouseOver">
<WebServiceSettings Method="GetToolTipData" 
Path="InvestmentDropDownWebService.asmx" UseHttpGet="true"/>
<TargetControls>
    <telerik:ToolTipTargetControl  TargetControlID="link"></telerik:ToolTipTargetControl>
</TargetControls> </telerik:RadToolTipManager> </asp:LinkButton>
```

And  this is the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = getName();
    link.Text = dt.Rows[0][Name].ToString();
}
```

I am trying this code but the problem is that on mouseover, the  webservice is not called. If I set link button Text in .aspx page it's working fine...

How to solve it if the text is from codebehind?

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tooltip/examples/tooltipversustooltipmanager/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: another solution please

Comment: that link is for your reference... its not a solution

Answer (score 0):

did you tried by using by giving empty text in aspx page like

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="link" runat="server" Text=" "> <telerik:RadToolTipManager
ID="toottip" runat="server" AutoTooltipify="true" Width="200px"
RelativeTo="Element"  HideEvent="LeaveTargetAndToolTip"
WebServiceSettings-UseHttpGet="false" Animation="Fade"  
EnableTheming="true" Title="Documents" ShowEvent="OnMouseOver">
<WebServiceSettings Method="GetToolTipData" 
Path="InvestmentDropDownWebService.asmx" UseHttpGet="true"/>
<TargetControls>
    <telerik:ToolTipTargetControl  TargetControlID="link"></telerik:ToolTipTargetControl>
</TargetControls> </telerik:RadToolTipManager> </asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: @user2849657 just try some demo data like "Hover" or something... and try replace on pageload...and mouse over link button. Check this please...